# GroupMe API Callback

Tags: android, api, callback, groupme

So, I am trying to use GroupMe's API. The issue is that I don't really know how to get the users access_token once I send them to the site to login. I don't really know how to create a callback or how to use it. So to sum it up

I need to send users to this site
`https://oauth.groupme.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID`,
then they login and groupme sends them to here
`https://YOUR_CALLBACK_URL/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`.

But I don't know how/where to create a callback url. Then I don't know how to send that access_token back to the app.

Thanks.

Comment: You are including your client id when sending them to that URL correct?

Comment: Were you ever able to find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

A callback URL is simply a url exposed by your app that groupme can redirect users to. The page can be anything, however, oftentimes it takes the user back to your app if it is a webapp, or tells the user to close the page.

The important part is that the url is one that the app controls, so that it can get the contents of the url that contain the token and other data.

If you are writing a web app, then the framework or language should a method or variable you can call or read to get the url. If you are writing a desktop/moble app, one way of creating a callback url is to listen on a tcp port and speak http to the browser. Another way is using a lightweight web server library, or use a lightweight external server like lighthttp and communicate using cgi/fastcgi. All that matters is that you can get the url that groupme se,t the user to.

If you need anymore help, you are using Oauth2 so search for help with that. Nothing that you asked about here is specfic to groupme, so you should be able to use any OAuth2 library.